# What is the difference between spark-shell and pyspark, in terms of the language we use to write codes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-shell

I wrote

```
 a = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
```

in spark-shell and got error

```
error: illegal start of simple expression
       a = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
                      ^
```

but when I wrote this in PySpark, it worked.

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: That's the difference between Scala and Python.

Comment: okay. so scala works in spark shell and python in pyspark?

Comment: Correct.  When using spark-shell, it expects Scala syntax

Answer (score 2):

You need to use scala to utilize spark-shell. In this case, it would be something like this

```
 val a = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3))
```